# What is the difference between these two LINQ Queries and how to correctly optimize them?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Clients table which has the following columns:
Id, FirstName, LastName, CurrencyId, Gender.

I want to select the client's Currency that corresponded to Id 10 so I am doing something like this:

```
var currencyId = Db.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id == 10)?.CurrencyId;
```

Does this line bring all properties from Db and selects the currency in the code or it executes something like this in the database:

```
SELECT currencyId FROM Client WHERE ID = 10
```

Or I should write the linq like this:

```
var currencyId = Db.Clients.Where(c=>c.Id == 10).Select(c=>c.CurrnecyId).FirstOrDefault();
```

What's the difference between the two queries?
And what is the correct way to translate the above SQL query into a linq query?

Comment: Nothing.  You would have to see the SQL Command Text to determine the differences.

Comment: @jdweng Not true at all - these queries are different. The first one can throw an exception while the second one would give you a default value (e.g. `0`)

Comment: @DavidG notice the "?" I added after the firstOrDefault() of the first query so that it doesn't throw an exception

Comment: OK, but it's still different. The first one will give you `null` and the second still gives a default value like `0`.

Comment: @DavidG Ok thanks. but is there a difference in the translated  SQL query ?

Comment: That depends on the provider you're using, why don't you figure out yourself what query is being generated?

Comment: In terms of generated SQL I expect them to be the same, but still would recommend checking via db profiler.

Comment: its a funny question, and i agree with @GuruStron, but may i ask why thats relevant, just out of curiosity?

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer Why is it funny? I am curious about the performance of the two queries

Comment: Performance questions can only be answered by you - run them together and figure out which one is faster. Use tools to help, like Benchmark.NET

Comment: @Artavazd i meant "funny" as in "interesting"

Comment: @DavidG I don't see a problem with my question. there are tons of performance-related questions here!

Comment: 99% of perf questions are dependant on a million things we have no insight into. We don't know which provider you're using, which database stack you have, the hardware it runs on, the data inside the tables etc. etc. It's not a bad question, but only you can get the real answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked into it myself cause I found the anwser from most people questionable. I expect the `FirstOrDefault` to materialize the result (you also see from the type that you are not longer working with a query object), so that would mean it queries for all properties.

Unlike the 2nd query where you are still working with a query when filtering the property you like, thus dependent on the implementation it could be used for filtering properties and selecting specific fields.

The following is an example of the queries generated using EF for two similar queries, where it shows both generating different queries: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5aFJAZ

Comment: hi, you are right, but to be hypercorrect, a) your program does not prove that point unless you do both queries in a separate context..which i did and the results were the same
b) it should be "it could be used for filtering properties and selecting specific fields"

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer yep :) you're entirely correct. I've added the feedback in the anwser

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `var currencyId = Db.Clients.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id == 10)?.CurrencyId;` the query selects the entire object to memory and then returns the Id property from that in memory object. As a result it needs to do something like the following SQL: `SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE Id = 10`. I understand I'm not using a parameter here and EF does spell out every column. However the key to understand here is that by returning more columns than you need, you potentially are setting up a performance concern because a covering index on Id and CurrencyId would not be used.

Your second LINQ query would use a SQL statement like `SELECT CurrencyId FROM Clients Where Id = 10` which would take advantage of your indexes assuming you have an index covering these columns.